# Read from group array

Tags: php, arrays, offset

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| Type          |  Price          |
+---------------+-----------------+
| Music         |  19.99          |
| Music         |   3.99          |
| Music         |  21.55          |
| Toy           |  89.95          |
| Toy           |   3.99          |
| Phones        |  99.99          |
| Phones        |  89.99          |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

I have the above data displayed as below using this code:

```
// Get the sum
$group = array();
foreach($rows as $r){
  $group[$r->type] = $group[$r->Type] + $r->Price;
}

// Display
foreach($group as $type=>$price){
  echo "Type:".$type." Price: ".$price;
}
```

Result:

```
Music  | 45.53
Toy    | 93.94
Phones | 189.98
```

My problem is how to display the data from the array (`$group`) starting from the second record and also how to display just one record from the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `array_slice()`;

```
//this will create new array without first element
$new_group = array_slice($group, 1);
```

And now iterate over `$new_group` as before.

Comment: Wonderful answer. I was going to edit it to set the offset to 0 and length to 1 until I realised the method returns the extracted values.

Answer (score 2):

If memory is not a concern (the array is not very large), use `array_slice` as [suggested by Peter Krejci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828482/php-read-from-group-array#answer-8828518). However, if it *is* a concern, you'll want to avoid duplicating all that data by simply skipping the first element:

```
$first = true;
foreach ($group as $type=>$price) {
    if ($first) {
        $first = false;
        continue;
    }
    echo "Type:", $type, " Price: ", $price;
}
```

I'm using this method rather than direct numerical index as there's no guarantee that the indexes are gapless. One could alternatively use the internal pointer functions, e.g., [next](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) but those have fallen out of favor in this age of the *Iterator* interface.

> also how to display just one record from the array

That depends which criteria you wish to access it by. If you want to do it by type, you can simply:

```
echo $group['Music'];
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to this and couldn't work out how to implement your approach. All the same thanks. I'm sure it'll help in the future and would definitely help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Try `array_shift($group)`, and then the `foreach()`.

From the [array_shift() documentation](https://www.php.net/array_shift):

> array_shift() shifts the first value of the array off and returns it,
> shortening the array by one element and moving everything down. All
> numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero
> while literal keys won't be touched.